# Отследить событие выключения расширения в Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, chrome-extension

Необходимо отследить событие на выключение расширения Google Chrome в самом расширении. Написал расширение, теперь надо сделать статистику сколько раз его включают и выключают.
Задача - отследить переключатель вкл/выкл расширения.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак вы это не отследите.

Все события жизненного цикла расширения находятся в [`chrome.runtime API`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime) и на данный момент их всего 5:

1. `onStartup`
2. `onInstalled`
3. `onSuspend`
4. `onSuspendCanceled`
5. `onUpdateAvailable`

Как видите такого события как "выключение" расширения просто нет. Более того, там даже нет события "удаление" (uninstall).

Answer (score 1):

Не могу ещё ответить под hindmost.

Есть событие удаления, точнее открытие страницы после удаления:

```
chrome.runtime.setUninstallURL('http://example.com');
```

Также добавлю, что событие onInstalled имеет два состояния
chrome.runtime.onInstalled имеет install и update

```
chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(function(details){
    alert(details.reason);
});
```

В англоязычной SO предлагают вариант следить через другое расширение. Уверен не подойдёт для ТС, но по другому пока адекватных вариантов нет.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13979781/chrome-extension-how-to-handle-disable-and-enable-event-from-browser

Если коротко:

Следить можно через chrome.management.onEnabled и chrome.management.onDisabled

Для этого создаётся новое расширение и добавляется разрешение в манифесте (manifest.json)

```
"permissions": [
    "management"
],
```

И в background.js добавляется наблюдение

```
chrome.management.onDisabled.addListener(function(ExtensionInfo) {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(ExtensionInfo));
});
```

Ну и дальше думаю понятно.

[Ссылка на API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/management.html)

Могу предложить неадекватное и не очень точное решение. В некоторых случаях оно может подойти.

Алгоритм такой:

1. Отсылаем на свой сервер раз в X минут (например раз в 10 минут) любой ID
   клиента. Сгенерировать его можно при установке. То есть пингуем (xhr, веб-сокеты и или как ещё, ваше дело).
2. В случае если пропал, то ждём его некоторое время, допустим сутки. Если он не объявился, то велика вероятность, что расширение
   отключено
3. "Появление" расширения можно получать по onStartup и по пингу из первого пункта. Событие onStartup срабатывает ТОЛЬКО при запуске, если пошёл пинг без события onStartup, то тут варианты

   - расширение было отключено
   - у пользователя пропадал интернет
   - компьютер был в спящем режиме.
     Второй и третий вариант можно также обойти - установив какой-нибудь счётчик, то есть с пингом слать не только ID, но и номер пакета (i++). Который при включение расширения, перезапуске браузера (напомню. что его проверяем через onStartup) будет начинаться с нуля.

Таким неадекватным способом можно относительно точно определять включено/выключено. Исключения, если пользователь долго не включает браузер можно будет сравнить с отключением расширения без удаления (события на удаление в алгоритм выше тоже надо добавить, но это уже другая история).